# topology on the extended real line defined by neighbourhood bases

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I would like to understand precisely how the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ can be extended to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}:=\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty,\infty\}$. The book I'm reading defines therefore the following neighbourhood bases: Additionally to the bases $\{(x-\epsilon,x +\epsilon) : \epsilon >0\}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ one adds $\{(c,+\infty] : c \in \mathbb{R}\}$ for $+\infty$ and $\{[-\infty,c) : c \in \mathbb{R}\}$ for $-\infty$.

This approach raises the question to me: under which conditions does a neighborhood bases define a topology. I'm only familiar with the concept of a basis, so an arbitrary set $\mathcal{M}$ of subsets of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ defines a topology on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ if the union of all sets of $\mathcal{M}$ is equal to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and the intersection of two sets in $\mathcal{M}$ can be represented by an arbitrary union of sets in $\mathcal{M}$.

So if I define $\mathcal{M}:=\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\{(x-\epsilon,x +\epsilon) : \epsilon >0\} \cup \{(c,+\infty] : c \in \mathbb{R}\} \cup \{[-\infty,c) : c \in \mathbb{R}\}$, then the union of all elements in $\mathcal{M}$ equals $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and each intersection of two elements from $\mathcal{M}$ is empty or again in $\mathcal{M}$. Thus $\mathcal{M}$ defines a unique topology on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

Are these considerations correct?

Comment: This $\mathcal M$ happens to be indeed a basis of (the open sets of) the topology on $\bar{\Bbb R}$, but that is not exactly what the authors means. Instead of defining the open sets as arbitrary union of elements of $\mathcal M$, they define them as the sets $E$ atisfying the following three conditions: $\forall x\in E\cap\Bbb R\quad\exists\epsilon>0\quad(x-\epsilon,x +\epsilon)\subseteq E$ and $+\infty\in E\implies\exists c\in\Bbb R\quad(c+\infty]\subset E$ and $-\infty\in E\implies\exists c\in\Bbb R\quad[-\infty,c)\subset E$.

Comment: For more information about topologies defined by neighborhoods, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiomatic_foundations_of_topological_spaces#Definition_via_neighbourhoods

Comment: Note also that your space is homeomorphic to the closed unit interval $[0, 1]$, taken as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ in the usual topology.